# CMake is unable to find library on Raspberry Pi Pico project. ld cannot find -lcustom_gpio: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I have been learning to write drivers for a Pi Pico and I implemented my own GPIO library.

But I am unable to get it to build as the linker is not able to find the library (-lcustom_gpio).

This is how my project directory looks.

```
.
└── LED_Blink/
    ├── build
    ├── gpio/
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── gpio.cpp
    │   └── gpio.hpp
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── main.hpp
    └── pico_sdk_import.cmake
```

CmakeLists.txt under gpio:

```
set(gpio_files gpio.cpp gpio.hpp)

add_library(custom_gpio ${gpio_files})
```

CMakeLists.txt under root:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)
project(test_project C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
pico_sdk_init()

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)



add_executable(test
${SOURCE_FILES}
)
target_link_libraries(test custom_gpio)
target_include_directories(test ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gpio)
pico_add_extra_outputs(test custom_gpio)
```

Output of 'cmake ..':

```
PICO_SDK_PATH is /home/arun/pico/pico-sdk
PICO platform is rp2040.
Build type is Release
PICO target board is pico.
Using board configuration from /home/arun/pico/pico-sdk/src/boards/include/boards/pico.h
TinyUSB available at /home/arun/pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; enabling build support for USB.
BTstack available at /home/arun/pico/pico-sdk/lib/btstack
cyw43-driver available at /home/arun/pico/pico-sdk/lib/cyw43-driver
Pico W Bluetooth build support available.
lwIP available at /home/arun/pico/pico-sdk/lib/lwip
mbedtls available at /home/arun/pico/pico-sdk/lib/mbedtls
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/arun/pico/LED_Blink/build
```

output of 'make -j4':

```
Scanning dependencies of target bs2_default
[  5%] Performing build step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[ 10%] Performing build step for 'PioasmBuild'
[ 20%] Built target bs2_default
[100%] Built target elf2uf2
[100%] Built target pioasm
[ 25%] No install step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[ 30%] No install step for 'PioasmBuild'
[ 35%] Completed 'ELF2UF2Build'
[ 40%] Completed 'PioasmBuild'
[ 65%] Built target ELF2UF2Build
[ 90%] Built target PioasmBuild
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target test
[ 95%] Linking CXX executable test.elf
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lcustom_gpio: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:97: test.elf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1490: CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I have been referring to related StackOverflow threads and CMake documentation, but I am stuck getting this project to build.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Root doesn't seem to include the gpio subfolder?

Comment: By Root I mean 'LED_Blink'

Comment: Yep, I understood that, I meant that your root cmake file isn't including the gpio subfolder

Comment: include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gpio)

Does this line not include the gpio subfolder?

Comment: It adds it to the compiler include paths, it doesn't add the cmake files in that directory, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html

Comment: Thank you for the information, I did not know that. 
However I face another linker error: undefined reference to function_name().

I had included this line in the root makefile:
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gpio)

Comment: You also need [target_link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_directories.html).

Comment: @IanAbbott not for linking to a target, cmake should do it all for you

Comment: BTW, `test` is a reserved target name in some versions of CMake. Even if it causes no problems now, it would be better to avoid calling a target `test`. And `target_include_directories` has a mandatory scope argument, e.g. `PUBLIC`.